# select sequelize realiza consulta diferente dos parâmetros passados com datetime

Tags: node.js, sequelize-js

Esta é a função que realiza a query:

```js
router.get('/out_filtered', async (req, res, next) => {
    try {
        const dateStart = req.body.date_start;
        const dateEnd = req.body.date_end;
        console.log('start', dateStart);
        console.log('end', dateEnd);

        const where = {
            date_create: {
                [Op.between]: [dateStart, dateEnd],
            }
        };

        const result = await cashFlowOutsModel.findAll({
            where,
            logging: console.log
        });


        return res.status(200).send(result);

    } catch (err) {
        console.log(err)
        res.logger.log('error', err);
        return res.status(500).send(err);
    }
});
```

Como estou passando os parâmetros:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
Como é feito a requisição, pelo log do console:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
Os horários que são passados via parâmetro não correspondem à consulta.

Comment: Qual o banco que voce esta usando? postgres ou mysql? se for postgres, acho que sei qual o problema.

Comment: Se possivel, mostre como esta configurado o seu `const sequelize = new Sequelize()`.

Comment: const Sequelize = require('sequelize');

Comment: estou usando mysql

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ao usar o Sequelize, é possível que ocorra um problema na hora de recuperar a hora  banco de dados. O Sequelize converte a hora da data para a hora UTC. E como se o sequelize reconhecesse a hora no campo de entrada como a hora UTC, logo baseado na `timezone`, ele adiciona mais 2 horas (baseado no log que voce mostrou) se o `timezone` estiver com alguma valor.

Nessa situação, é necessário alterar a configuração do Sequelize para obter os registros adequados sem alteracao de hora. Tente fazer esse ajuste na configuracao do sequelize:

```js
const sequelize = new Sequelize('db_name', 'user', 'password', {
     host: '<seu host>',
     dialectOptions: {
      useUTC: false     // para considerar a hora da consulta como a hora 
                        // local, logo nao soma +02:00 horas
     },
     dialect: 'mysql',
     timezone: '+02:00',// para salvar a data baseado no fuso horario
});
```